# Problem with installing format Junkie in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 utropic unicorn. I tried to install format junkie by following the instructions given in the link below. Previously, I had installed format Junkie in ubuntu 12.04 LTS by looking at the link below and it worked well.

[How To Install Format Junkie 1.08](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-format-junkie-1-08-on-ubuntu-14-04-linux-mint-17-pinguy-os-14-04-deepin-2014-and-other-ubuntu-14-04-derivative-systems/)

But this time with 14.10, itseems much more complicated. I added ppa to my repositories but when I update the packages, error occurs out of nowhere. Ubuntu Guru's, please help me as I really need that package in my computer.

Comment: Quoting from the link: `The latest version available is Format Junkie 1.08, which comes with support for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr and good Unity integration`. Are you sure it will support `14.10`? Also please add what have you done so far and what error messages you are getting in exact form.

Comment: If there is no package integration for utopic then you simply cannot use it.